# Android: toggle text color of ToggleButton

Tags: android, android-xml, togglebutton

To create a custom ToggleButton, I've defined a new style in `/res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="myToggleButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_toggle_button</item>
</style>
```

and I then use a selector to specify how the button's states look in `/res/drawable/my_toggle_button.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape>
            [...]
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        <shape>
            [...]
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

How can I modify this setup to toggle the text color of the button when the state changes?

Comment: in shape scope, give color paremeters want you want and delete background in style.xml.

Comment: I think this link is useful for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096599/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-an-android-tooglebutton-on-state-change

Comment: Based on experimentation with auto-complete in Eclipse, that link does not give valid syntax.  The only possible way to specify a colour is `<color android:color=""/>` in the scope of `<item>`.  It doesn't change the text colour, though.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Create a similar state list for the text colors you would like, and place it in `res/color`, e.g.

`res/color/toggle_color.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#070" />
    <!-- Default State -->
    <item android:color="#A00" />
</selector>
```

Then set this resource as the text color of the button:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/toggle_color</item>
```

P.S., it's good practice to have the last item in a selector not have any state flags attached (i.e. a default state) rather than defining it with the inverse of the above states.

Comment: very helpful answer - but I found it didn't run only because upper case characters aren't allowed in the filename (API version 18 at least) - made edit :)