# change toggle button text color through xml

Tags: android, toggle, android-button, togglebutton, android-togglebutton

Hi i'm trying to change the color of **toggle button's text** through xml.

I have referred links but its only changing the background color of toggle button but not its text.

I tried with this approach :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

but only the background is changing.

**Note : I don't want to do it in code since there are 21 toggle buttons and setting listeners for each of them is not good.**

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065200/android-toggle-text-color-of-togglebutton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065200/android-toggle-text-color-of-togglebutton)

Comment: i'm doing this 

`<ToggleButton
                                android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
                                style="@style/toggleButton"/>`

`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#00FF00"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="#FF0000"/>

</selector>
`



 `<style name="toggleButton" parent="@android:Theme.Black">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color</item>
 </style>`

what is wrong in this?

Comment: @yasshy Instead of creating `Style` try to set `Drawable` to your `Toggle Button` like `android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector"`

Comment: instead of `style="@style/toggleButton"`

tried with `android:background="@style/toggleButton"`

showing inflation error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't set the parent of a widget style to be a theme. Instead, you'll want to set it to be the default widget style that you want to modify (e.g. @android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Toggle).

In your case, however, you don't need to use a style:

res/color/toggle_text.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

res/layout/your_layout.xml:

```
...
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    ...
    android:textColor="@color/toggle_text" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I din't notice the attribute `android:textColor` which is required.